# How to create a text line break within a div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some text which is flowing over the box border I have made. I've tried using `display` to break it up into two lines, but is there any other way of using css or html to divide it?

Css

```
.awpcp-listing-title {display: table-column;}
```

doesn't work

```
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt $awpcpdisplayaditems 
$isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp- 
listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], 
"small": [328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
$awpcp_image_name_srccode
</div>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
<h4 class="awpcp-listing-title">$title_link</h4>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-content">$excerpt</div>
</div>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">

$awpcp_city_display
$awpcp_state_display
$awpcp_display_adviews
$awpcp_display_price
$awpcpextrafields
```

Answer (score 0):

for overflowing text you can white-space and word-break property to control how text should be wrapped and break into a second line.

for example:

```
.break-words{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not overflowing the size of the div, it's overflowing the size of the artifical box I've created for it. So how would I apply `break-words` to that specific div class?

Comment: if you remove 
all position relative and top,left negative values it will make your life easier, it not prefect practice to do this

Comment: I mean something is stopping it displaying because, when I use `display: table-column;` is shows for a split second during loading and then disappears.

Comment: Maybe if I try `unset`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the green highlighted text on the rounded cards? If so, you have a line-height property of 80px set, which is causing the text to push outside the box. This should fix that, assuming that's what you're talking about:

```css
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: You see how the text with green background is sticking out from the box `The Plumed Serpent-D. H Lawrence?` Here: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/ That's the div class I'm talking about `awpcp-listing-title`. So i want to target that div class so that, when someone posts an ad, the text will break in order that it doesn't go outside the box. Tried: line-height: normal; doesn't work, but something is stopping the green thing displaying as it shows for a split second during page loading and then disappears.

Comment: @Amamda, I should be able to use `display: table-column; which again shows for a split second during page loading, then disappears. At the moment I've got display: inherit;, but that puts all the text on one line instead of two.